# How can i plot this piece of code with ggplot2?

Tags: shapefile, r, cartography, ggplot2

I have these vectors of the lakes in New Guinea and the coastline and  i want to plot it using ggplot2 exactly as it follows but with a more cool appearance.

```
co<-coastline.shp
nglakes<-lakes.shp
plot(co,col="yellow")
plot(nglakes,col="blue",add=T)
legend("topleft",legend=c("LAND","LAKE"),title="LineTypes",col=c("yellow","blue"),lty=1,cex=0.8)
```

Comment: Could you provide enough code for a reproducible example? What do you mean by 'more cool'? What specifically are you looking to do?

Comment: More professional i mean.You can use similar shapefiles to make it if you want. The idea is to make a map using the corresponding code in ggplot2.

Comment: How about posting your shape files? And perhaps a snapshot of what you have in mind for your final map? "More professional" might mean different things do different people.

Comment: Seeking the same as what you have but with a "more cool appearance" makes this open to opinion as to what is cool.  In addition I think a question that seems like "I've done the easy bit, now give me ideas for how to embellish" makes it too broad also,

Comment: Actually not my favourite question, but I really like the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used 10-m lake shapefile data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/) along with country borders from **rworldmap** to reproduce what I guess you were trying to achieve. Hadley Wickham wrote a nice tutorial on [how to visualize spatial data using ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) and I strongly encourage you to have a look at it. Still, a short workaround is required in order to get the visualization to work with fragmented polygons as it is the case for Papua New Guinea. Check out the following code.

```
## required packages
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)
library(raster)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

## import lake shapefile
nglakes <- readOGR("data", "ne_10m_lakes")

## select papua new guinean lakes only
data(countriesCoarse)
ng <- subset(countriesCoarse, ADMIN == "Papua New Guinea")

nglakes <- crop(nglakes, ng)

## transform shapefile into data.frame
nglakes@data$id = rownames(nglakes@data)
nglakes.points = fortify(nglakes, region = "id")
nglakes.df = join(nglakes.points, nglakes@data, by = "id")
nglakes.df$Type <- "Lake"

## base ggplot
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat), data = ng, fill = NA, colour = NA) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")

## gradually add polygons to existing plot
n <- 1
for (i in ng@polygons[[1]]@Polygons) {

  # convert each sub-polygon to 'spatialpolygonsdataframe' 
  pys <- Polygons(list(i), ID = n)
  spys <- SpatialPolygons(list(pys), proj4string = CRS(proj4string(ng)))
  spysdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spys, data = data.frame(ID = n), match.ID = FALSE)

  # transform sub-polygon shapefile into data.frame
  spysdf@data$id <- rownames(spysdf@data)
  spysdf.points <- fortify(spysdf, region = "id")
  spysdf.df <- join(spysdf.points, spysdf@data, by = "id")
  spysdf.df$Type <- "Land"

  # add sub-polygon to existing plot
  p <- p + 
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = Type), data = spysdf.df, 
                 colour = "grey65")
  n <- n + 1
}

## add lake polygon
p + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = Type), data = nglakes.df) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Land" = "yellow", "Lake" = "blue")) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(1, 0), legend.justification = c(1, 0))
```

[image: map]
Does this come close at what you were trying to figure out?

Comment: +1 In contrast to the question this looks like a great answer.